# ClassCastException in interface extends

Tags: java, interface

I have this code for AuctionTable interface:

```
    public interface AuctionTable extends AtlasWebElement<AuctionTable> {
        ...
        default HybridTable getHybridTable() {
            return (HybridTable) this;
        }
    }
```

And this code for HybridTable interface:

```
public interface HybridTable extends AuctionTable {
}
```

What i am doing wrong? Because i see this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57 cannot be cast to HybridTable
```

AuctionTable instance i get from this:

```
public interface AuctionPage extends MainPage {
    @FindBy("//div[@data-test-id='briefTable_{{ briefId }}']")
    ElementsCollection<AuctionTable> briefByID(@Param("briefId") int briefId);

     default AuctionTable getBriefByID(int briefId) {
         return briefByID(briefId).get(0);
     }
    
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted is not enough to identify the problem. Add some use-cases, e.g. where is `AuctionTable` instance is obtained from

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko is that better?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are doing a peculair thing here.

In your `AuctionTable` interface, you are defining a default interface method `getHybridTable` with the following body:

```java
return (HybridTable) this;
```

`this` refers to the very instance of some type implementing `AuctionTable`, but you cast it to a *specific* subtype of `AuctionTable`, that is, `HybridTable`. You nor the compiler can guarantee that `this` is always a `HybridTable`. And in this case, it apparently isn't, hence the exception.

You have to ask yourself whether the `getHybridTable` method belongs within your `AuctionTable` type. I think it doesn't.

Comment: is it not a downcasting?